# JDBC DatabaseMetaData says that my mysql server has no support for namedParameters and accordingly throws a null pointer exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, nullpointerexception

Im back on java recently, and i am struggling making the following method work:

```
@Override
public T createEntity(T entity) throws SQLException{
    DatabaseMetaData dbMeta  = connection.getMetaData();
    boolean okay = dbMeta.supportsNamedParameters();
    if(okay) {
        System.out.println("Supports named arguments");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Does not support named arguments");
    }
    CallableStatement cstmt = connection.prepareCall("create_" + table.getName() + "(" + columns.stream().map( column -> "?").collect(Collectors.joining(","))  + ")");

    final ThrowingConsumer<DatabaseColumn> throwingConsumer = column -> {
       try {
        String alright = "herpderp";
        cstmt.setObject(column.getName(), entity.getClass().getDeclaredField(column.getName()).get(entity) /**, SQLType targetSqlType ?? */ );
           ParameterMetaData meta =   cstmt.getParameterMetaData();
       } catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    };
    columns.stream().forEach(throwingConsumer);

    cstmt.execute();
    return null;
}
```

The call:

```
cstmt.setObject(column.getName(), entity.getClass().getDeclaredField(column.getName()).get(entity) /**, SQLType targetSqlType ?? */ );
```

Fails with a nullpointer exception, i have checked that both of the values goes in are just fine, but eventually it just does a null pointer. The prepared statement also looks just fine.  I am trying to use namedParameters so that is what i think is the culprit, i tried to check if my setup was even compatible with namedParameters, and it turns out that DatabaseMetaData doesn't think so, in the following code:

```
DatabaseMetaData dbMeta  = connection.getMetaData();
boolean okay = dbMeta.supportsNamedParameters();
if(okay) {
    System.out.println("Supports named arguments");
} else {
    System.out.println("Does not support named arguments");
}
```

. The following is my versions:

```
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.3'

    mysql: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.13, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

so pretty much the newest of the newest.

If i run through it with the debugger, a scenario where this gives a nullpointer looks like this:

```
cstmt.setObject("email", "herpderp@gmail.com");
```

Where the orginalSql field in the callableStatement looks like this:

```
create_account(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `create_account`(email VARCHAR(45), username VARCHAR (45), pw VARCHAR (45), guid VARCHAR(45), verified tinyint(4))
BEGIN
insert into account (`email`, `username`, `password`, `guid`, `verified`) values (email, username, pw, guid, verified);
END
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your question? Also, did you read the javadoc of [`CallableStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) for how to build the call in a standard way?

Comment: Yeah the question might be too general, the question is just - why doesn't the CallableStatement work with namedParameters, even though its happening by the book and everything is updated. But i am going to try to replicate the bug in a more simple example instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling a stored procedure, it goes like this:

```
 CallableStatement cstmt = connection.prepareCall("{CALL create_" + table.getName() + "(" + columns.stream().map( column -> "?").collect(Collectors.joining(","))  + ")}");
```

Without the CALL, its no good, wouldve just wished the error messages was more helpful, obviously a complete brainfart :)